# Как правильно реализовывается интервал в C++?

Tags: c++

Нужно каждые N миллисекунд увеличивать переменную. Нашёл только такой способ:

```
long t = time(0)

while (...) {
  if (time(0) > t) {
      ...
      t = time(0);
   }
}
```

Только это слишком медленно. Sleep внутри циклов не работает. Я что-то делаю не так, но не могу понять, что.

Как в C++ правильно сделать интервал без костылей?

Comment: *"Sleep внутри циклов не работает"* В каком смысле? Можно подробнее?

Comment: Он будто игнорируется. Пробовал и в for и в while, результат один. Цикл внутри функции, которая бесконечно вызывается в main. Но я проверил, функция выполняется правильно, дожидаясь конца цикла.

Comment: @АлексейПетродий, быть может интервал просто слишком мал, чтобы заметить остановку?

Comment: Покажите ваш код со `sleep` и расскажите, как определили, что он игнорируется.

Comment: В `time()` и `sleep()` время в секундах, а в [usleep()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html) микросекунды. Почитайте также разделы `NOTES` и `SEE ALSO` в manpage по ссылке

Comment: Просто добавлял функцию Sleep в цикл. Результат игнорируется. Sleep виндовый, забыл написать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функции ожидания (sleep, usleep, sleep_for), не обеспечивают точного периода ожидания. Они гарантируют только, что период будет "не меньше" указанного пользователем. Проблема в том, что многие OS, включая windows, не являются real-time os. Т.е. если конец интервала придется на квант времени когда шедуллер уже отдал процессор другому процессу, работа твоей программы продолжиться физически не сможет.

Правильный способ - заменить обращение к переменной, на обращение к функции, и внутри функции вычислять результат на основе текущего времени. Либо довольствоваться "приблизительным" интервалом времени.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте [std::this_thread::sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) для c++11

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за помощь. Извините, не разобрался. Перепутал функцию, виндовый Sleep принимает только миллисекунды. Я действительно слишком малое значение поставил.